# find_or_create_by in multiple create action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I was able to create multiple records at once using the create methode below:

```
  def create    
    rate_price = params[:rate][:rate]
    mlos = params[:rate][:mlos]

    start_date = Date.parse(params[:start_date])
    end_date = Date.parse(params[:end_date])

    dates = (start_date..end_date).to_a.select {|k| (params[:rate][:days]).reject(&:blank?).map(&:to_i).include?(k.wday)}
    room_ids = params[:rate][:room_ids].reject(&:blank?).map(&:to_i)

    @rates = []
    dates.zip(room_ids).each do |date, room_id|
      rate = Rate.new(:rate => rate_price, :mlos => mlos, :room_id => room_id, :dayrate => date )
      #rate = Rate.find_or_create_by_dayrate(date, :rate => rate_price, :mlos => mlos, :room_id => room_id)

      @rates << rate
    end

    @rates.map(&:save)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @rates.any? { |rate| !rate.persisted? } 
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @rates.detect { |rate| !rate.persisted? }.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Rates were successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @rates, status: :created, location: @rates }
      end
    end
  end
```

But when I want to create or update the records (if they already exists) using `find_or_create_by`(commented line in my code), no records seems to be updated, only the create works.
Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the method is called, `find_or_create_by` is only used when you want to create a new record.  From what I understand with your code, you want to create a rate using a `dayrate` which is a date column.  And since your question is why the records aren't update, I'm assuming that you want to update the records if they are already in the db.  You can achieve that using the following code

```
rate = Rate.where(dayrate: date).first_or_initialize
rate.attributes = { rate: rate_price, mlos: mlos, room_id: room_id }
```

this will make sure that the rate's attributes will use the values you pass if they pass the validation (since you're calling `map(&:save)` after the block.